# How to schedule a method to check for server

Tags: android, android-handler

I am showing a listview with 2 values using baseadapter by fetching the data from web service. When new data hits server i want to update my listview automatically. For that i want to schedule the below method to periodically check server for data and update the list. How to do that. Please someone help me.

```
private void getEmployees() {
     List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
     headers.add(new BasicHeader("Accept", "application/json"));

     EmployeeRestClient.get(MainActivity.this, "RestExample/employee", 
    headers.toArray(new Header[headers.size()]),null, 
        new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
     ArrayList<Employee> employeeArray = new ArrayList<Employee>();


       for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
        try {
              employeeArray.add(new Employee(response.getJSONObject(i)));
             } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
     EmployeeAdapter employeeAdapter = new EmployeeAdapter(MainActivity.this, employeeArray);
       employeeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_employees);
      employeeList.setAdapter(employeeAdapter);
         }
    });
 }
```